# matplotlib subplot shrinks automatically

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I am currently using matplotlib to plot my images to subplots and as there are many images (as much as 100), the subplots shrinks automatically as there are too many subplots.

[subplots of 63 images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjLuf.png)

As you can see from the image, this is the issue I am currently facing.

I am wondering if there are any ways to fix the size of the subplots to prevent the automatic shrinking so they can be seen and also including a scrollable bar so that if there are over 100 images and all couldn't be fitted onto the figure, it will still maintain the size of the subplots and just allow the user to scroll and view all these images.
I am using TKagg backend.

I've tried doing:

```
 fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
```

to maintain the size of the subplots but it seems that this doesn't fix the images as the images still shrunk.

Comment: Is the point to display multiple images, and you just happen to use matplotlib, or do you require matplotlib?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think matplotlib is the best module if you want to show a large number of images.
A good alternative might be [Plotly](https://plotly.com/python/), combined with dash.

```
pip install dash
```

This will make it possible to generate many images onto a webpage, which automatically enables scrolling. Also you can now add a manual slider, such that you can select the part that you want.

In order to give some reference I will display two minimal working examples.

#### Option 1

This is the solution closest to your specifications of generating a grid of images, through which you can scroll (when they become too big), but also requires `dash_bootstrap` for the formatting and  `pillow` to convert images to base64.

It is build from two parts:

1. A `numpy` image convertor to base64, this is for serving the image as url to the `html.Img` component.
2. The dash app that creates a grid layout that will wrap around when changing the `width` or `height` value.

- Part 1:

```
import base64
from io import BytesIO

from PIL import Image


def arr_to_b64(array, ext='jpeg'):
    """ Convert an array to an image source that can be displayed."""
    image = Image.fromarray(array)
    if ext == 'jpg': ext = 'jpeg'
    if ext == 'jpeg' and image.mode in ('RGBA', 'A'):
        background = Image.new(image.mode[:-1], image.size, (255, 255, 255))
        background.paste(image, image.split()[-1])
        image = background

    buffer = BytesIO()
    image.save(buffer, format=ext)
    encoded = base64.b64encode(buffer.getvalue()).decode('utf-8')

    return f'data:image/{ext};base64, ' + encoded
```

- part 2 (this is the dash server)

```
import numpy as np

import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc  # Extra import besides `dash`

app = dash.Dash(__name__,
                external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])

images = np.random.randint(0, 255, (60, 30, 30, 3), dtype=np.uint8)

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.Div(id='image-output', className='d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-start m-5',
             children=[html.Img(src=arr_to_b64(image), className='m-1', width=100, height=100)
                       for image in images])
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(port='8051', debug=True)
```

Output:

[image: Grid image display]

#### Option 2

This is a slightly simpler to create example without requiring any knowledge of [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/). But doesn't display a grid, but a slider. This slider makes it possible to select a specific image.

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

images = np.random.randint(0, 255, (60, 30, 30, 3), dtype=np.uint8)

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    dcc.Slider(id='image-number', min=0, max=60, value=0,
               marks={key: str(key) for key in range(0, len(images), 5)},
               tooltip=dict(always_visible=True, placement='top')),
    html.Div(id='image-output'),
])


@app.callback(Output('image-output', 'children'),
              [Input('image-number', 'value')])
def update_image(idx):
    return dcc.Graph(figure=go.Figure(go.Image(z=images[idx])))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(port='8051', debug=True)
```

[image: Example output 1]

It might be possible to do with matplotlib, but sometimes the alternatives are easier.

Hopefully this will help you further.

Comment: Would've upvote you if I could as my reputation is too low. Thank you so much.

Comment: You marked it as the accepted answer, that is similar. Glad I could help.